# How can I break up a larger number into smaller numbers and exponents?

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

I'm trying to compute the Euler's totient function for large numbers where I can't use the other rules in order to solve for the totient.

For example:

$\theta(600) = (2^3 * 3 * 5^2)$

I am confused on how you can simplify 600 to to the numbers on the right hand of the expression.

Comment: You need to factorize $600$. To compute Euler's totient function [there seems to be nothing simpler](https://mathoverflow.net/a/3275).

Answer (score 1):

We have $600=2^3\cdot 3\cdot 5^2$ and 
$$
\phi(600)=\phi(2^3)\cdot \phi(3)\cdot\phi(5^2)=4\cdot 2\cdot 20=160.
$$
The factorisation of $600$ is easy, since $100=2^2\cdot 5^2$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but when I tried factoring $100 = 10^2$ and solved for the Euler's totient I got 180. $\theta(600) = 10^2 * 6 = (10^2 - 10) * 2 = 180$. The Euler totient of 6 is 2.

Comment: But $10$ is not prime, so $\phi(10^2)\neq10^2-10$.

Comment: Ohhh okay base numbers have to prime that makes sense